# What's Default Activity?

Tags: android, facebook

I am registering my app on `Facebook Developer`, which need to know what my Default Activity. Sorry if it's a stupid question but the Default Activity is my splashscreen (App boot with logo) or the first screen after loading the splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default activity is the starting activity that is defined as "MAIN" inside android manifest file

```
 <activity
     .......
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The one defined by action.MAIN intent in your AndroiManifest. Splashscreen in your case.